# Is there something similar to $\mathbb{R}^2$ for elliptic curve point representation?

Tags: field-theory, terminology, finite-fields, algebraic-curves, elliptic-curves

Let $E$ be an *elliptic curve* over a *finite field* $\mathbb{F}_p$ and denote with $E(\mathbb{F}_p)$ its set of points over $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Consider a coordinate system in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Every point is represented with an $x$- and $y$-coordinate.

Representing points on the elliptic curve you have to choose $x$- and $y$-coordinates as well, fulfilling the curve equation. So why are elliptic curves points defined over $\mathbb{F}_p$ and not over $\mathbb{F}_p^2$ ?

Comment: those points perhaps lie in $F_p^2$ or so

Comment: Sorry for the typo . $ F_p^2$ is what I actually to wanted write in the question

Comment: Aha, so each component of the points lies in $F_p$, I guess that makes them defined over $F_p$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"A point over $\mathbb{F}_p$" means exactly a point such that both of its coordinates are in $\mathbb{F}_p$, so (as you say) you have a point of $\mathbb{F}_p^2$ (actually, you really have a point in the *projective* plane over $\mathbb{F}_p$).  It's just the way you say it.  It is a useful terminology because you can also define points over $\mathbb{F}_p$ in an "abstract" elliptic curve (and other more general objects), which does not come with a chosen embedding into the projective plane (so there is no canonical choice of "coordinates" for the points).